# Determine if ls output is file or directory

Tags: ls

w/o colors " ls " command

```
1 2 3
```

unknown which is a folder which is a file.

can "ls" or some other command clarify which is file which is folder

perhaps by including ' / ' infront if : a folder ?

for example:

```
 /1 2 /3
```

Comment: Hey that guy that deleted his answer.. that was amazing help. I found out about the comma.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On Linux,

```
ls -p
```

adds the trailing slash on dirs

Comment: I wonder what `-p` stands for, the man page doesn't specify. I know that `-F` is for classifying as @dhag's answer mentioned

Comment: `-p` might stand for pretty printing

Comment: according to the man page 
'-p' stand for "slash" while '-F' stand for "classify":                                                              


`--indicator-style=WORD ... to  entry  names:  none  (default),  slash  (-p),   file-type (--file-type), classify (-F)`

Answer (score 13):

```
-F, --classify
       append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

Example output, where `1` and `2` are directories, and `3`, `4` are files:

```
$ ls -F
1/  2/  3  4
```

Answer (score 6):

Another method: ls -l displays the files and folders with permission bits. If the line starts with a -, it's a file, if it's a directory, it starts with a d.

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r--   1 user  group    7727 Feb 27 16:07 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   6 user  greup     204 Mar  3 09:20 my_directory
```